# Can TamperMonkey access scripts in a Github repository?

Tags: github, tampermonkey, gist

We have some TamperMonkey scripts that we use across our organization to help automate certain parts of our app for us.

We previously have had the author of those scripts save them to a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and TamperMonkey can somehow access them and facilitate installing them on user browsers. As these scripts have gotten more complex and with various features over time, we find it would be nice to have a dedicated repository for these with the ability to have pull requests made against those scripts.

As far as I know, a Gist can't have a pull request and only the owner of that Gist can make edits to them.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a Github repository with the scripts that we want to put under version control AND have TamperMonkey be able to access and install them as before?